# Java what is wrong with my timer?

Tags: java, timer

I have a timer to subtract a point of health if your person is starving, I want it to subtract a point every 10 seconds if he is starving, however as soon as the timer starts it loop removes health, what did I do wrong?

http://puu.sh/vAu2H.png This is the output to show what the result it. it removes health before the 10 seconds even finish.

Here is my code for my timer:

`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class GUI {

    public void tick() {
        if(Player.starving) {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            int begin = 0; //timer starts after 1 second.
            int timeinterval = 10 * 1000; //timer executes every 10 seconds.
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                //This code is executed at every interval defined by timeinterval (eg 10 seconds) 
               //And starts after x milliseconds defined by begin.
                    Player.health = Player.health - 1;
                    System.out.println(Player.health);
              }
            },begin, timeinterval);
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {
        Font menuFont = new Font( "SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 18);

        g.setFont(menuFont);

        g.setColor(Color.green);    
        g.drawString("Money: " + String.valueOf(Player.money) + " $", 655, 25);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("Health: " + String.valueOf(Player.health) + " / 5.0", 10, 25);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(Time.globalTime), Engine.WIDTH * Engine.SCALE / 2 + 30, 25);

        if(Player.health <= 0) {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, Engine.WIDTH, Engine.HEIGHT);

            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString("Your pet is dead :'(", Engine.WIDTH * Engine.SCALE / 2 - 75, Engine.HEIGHT * Engine.SCALE / 2);
        }
        tick();
    }
}
```

Here is a video of what I get: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3JwZh_rpqc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Question is a bit unclear around `soon as the timer starts it loop removes health`, perhaps you edit the question to show the actual vs desired output over time.

Comment: http://puu.sh/vAu2H.png It loop removes all of the health before the timer even finishes

Comment: You're asking why your code doesn't work, and to answer this well, we'll want to see more than a snippet and less than your whole code: a [mcve]. Please read the link and then consider creating one and posting it here fully with your question.

Comment: That is the whole code, thats all that could be wrong. I want to know why the timer isn't working. that should be all you need to see what is wrong with it...

Comment: This code works fine for me. It waits 1 second, and then every 10 seconds it takes off 1 health.

Comment: I'll make a video it doesn't at all for me.

Comment: Oh I see you added new code. Each time you call render you are starting a new timer that is taking health off every 10 seconds. You need to make sure if a timer is already going you don't start another.

Comment: @Robert Thank you, I'll figure this out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call render you are starting a new timer that is taking health off. You need to make sure if a timer is already going you don't start another.

Comment: so now the timer doesn't stop when I tell it to

Comment: Do you have the latest code? It should just be timer.cancel()